# ExpandableListView clear animation when opening

Tags: android, animation, expandablelistview

I developed two menu like in Facebook app. 
One of them contains expandableListView. 
*UseCase:*
I open the menu, then I open a section. Now, My translation is closed by the redrawn, So it hides my menu.

To open my menu, I apply translation and then remove it and use offsetLeftAndRight to keep it open:

```
mainlayout.clearAnimation();

mainlayout.offsetLeftAndRight(pxTranslateMenu);
```

I tried to create my own view to solve this problem. But I have the same result when my items go from GONE to VISIBLE. When items go from INVSIBLE to VISIBLE all is OK, but i have a wrong render (free space where my items are placed).

Is there anyway of doing what i want : Keeping my menu open after clicking on section?

Thanks.

I tried to use some other component to avoid Accordion.
But i have the same problem when an EditText take focus or when i select an item in an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to overpass this problem.
I just create a new activity wich has a translucent part. 
In this way, i can do what i want.

I hope that i'm gonna be able to resolve all demand by this way.